# How to extract numbers and special characters in a string in linux script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, numbers

I have a string like basedir=/cp/osp/peaker/1543.23. here i want to extract 1543.23, in linux script, could someone tell me how to do this here.

May be using sed, regex, i was unable to do. here i want 1543.23 (so i want number and special character . also).

Answer (score 2):

You could use `awk`. Something like

```
echo $basedir | awk 'BEGIN {FS="/"};{print $NF}'
```

That begins by setting the field separator (FS) to "/" and then printing the last field.

Comment: Its returning 20 ports, i want only one listening port, i gave the process id also.

Comment: You asked how to extract a number from a string... where did you say anything about ports, process ids or (in fact) any processes.